Transparent background is visible when imported into photoshop
I have a glass shape rendered in cycles, but when I import the shape into Photoshop, I can see a slight blackish background which is noticeable. How is this possible, the transparent background is seen when the shape is rendered, and saved as RGB Alpha.




Sorry, but I have problem to understand what I'm seeing in the last image compared to the ones above. Where is this, it seems to be a totally different view on the object. And I do not see a "noticeable slight blackish background" there, I see an almost completely black background which is more than noticeable.

could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

here's the file:


@GordonBrinkmann, if you place it in photoshop, and click on off the layer, you will notice there's a slight transparent background which rendered with the glass.

@blenderbreath You mean the plane behind the glass object which you have only disabled for the viewport, but not for render? Well, if you don't want it, just disable it for render or delete it: hidden plane

@GordonBrinkmann, good spotting, I had accidentally made the plane glass material, and didnt notice it even was in the layer panel. Thanks heaps!!!
